# Rational function and horizontal asymptote

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

Let $f(x)$ be a rational function of the form $\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $q(x) \neq 0$. Assume that $q(x)$ has two distinct roots $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ where $x_{1} < x_{2}$, and the degree of $p(x)$ is less that the degree of $q(x)$. If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_{1}^{+}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_{2}^{-}}f(x)$, is it guaranteed that $f(x)$ will not pass through the horizontal asymptote?

Comment: "Horizontal asymptote" ? By what you describe, $\;\deg f<\deg g\implies\;\;y=0\;$ is the only horizontal asymptote...

Comment: I am sorry if you misunderstood my question. I know that the only horizontal asymptote is $y = 0$, but what I am trying to ask is if it is guaranteed that $f(x)$ will not pass the line $y = 0$ if the region between the asymptotes decrease or increase without bound as it approaches any vertical asymptote.

Comment: I still am not sure I really understand what you mean: the function $\;f(x)\;$ will cross the line $\;y=0\;$ iff  the numerator $\;p(x)\;$  has real roots. I can't understand what the vertical asymptotes have to do with this...

Comment: For example, $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^{2}+2x}$. The vertical asymptotes are the lines $x = -2$ and $x = 0$. The behavior of the graph in between the vertical asymptotes is that it decreases without bound as $h$ takes values closer to either $-2$ or $0$.

Comment: Ok...and what that has to do with $\;h\;$ having or not real roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think of this one ?$$\frac{x^2-1}{x^4-2
}$$

[image]

Comment: I now get that the function can pass through the horizontal asymptote. But can I make a follow-up question? How will you know if it will pass through the horizontal asymptote?

Comment: @kevs924: roots of the numerator !

Comment: Oh, sorry. I totally forgot about that.